# YouTube app won't update on iPad 3

Tags: ipad, applications, youtube

I have an iPad 3 3G/WiFi with iOS 9.3.6.

When I try to use the YouTube app, an "Update required" dialogue pops up, but when I try to update from the App Store, it just displays "Open" with no update choice.

Searching online, I found out that Apple has stopped support for this old tablet, is there anything I can do other than buying a newer version of iPad?

My iPad is updated to the latest version of iOS. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your iPad has been released in March of 2012 and is now eight years
  old. It is normal that Apps and Apple will drop software support at some point.

### iOS updates and App updates are different.

- **iOS** is the **Operating systems** from **Apple** for their mobile devices and the newest version usually supports devices up to ~5 years old.
- **App updates** (in this case YouTube) are released from the **developer** (in this case Google). They may require a certain iOS version (which includes certain libraries and features that the App can use).

You are experiencing the second problem, where the App needs a newer version of iOS to run. However, your iPad is not being supported by Apple anymore.
That means in your case that there is **nothing** you can do about the **App update**.

What you could try though, is to open [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com) in your browser. Usually this works but I can only confirm this for newer devices.